# Spring Security - Roles

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am currently creating a banking application with spring security and I have an Enum class (Role) with two roles, User and Admin.

I am trying to implement it so that if you're going to /banking you must have ROLE_USER and if you're going to /admin you must have ROLE_ADMIN. However, I am getting errors logging in and it's not working. Even if the login is correct, it redirects me to the error page.

Security Config Class:

```
    @Bean
DaoAuthenticationProvider provider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsServiceImpl);
    provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    return provider;
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(provider());
    auth.userDetailsService(this.userDetailsServiceImpl);
}


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .and()
        .formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error").defaultSuccessUrl("/banking")
        .and()
          .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
        .and()
          .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
        .and()
          .csrf();
}
```

Register Controller Class:

```
    @PostMapping("/register")
public String register(Model model, @ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
    if ((userService.findByUsername(user.getUsername()) != null) || userService.findByEmail(user.getEmail()) != null) {
        model.addAttribute("errorRegister", "User already exists with that username or email!");
        return "redirect:/register";
    }
    user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    user.setBalance(25000);
    user.setEnabled(true);
    user.setRole("ROLE_" + Role.USER);
    userService.save(user);
    model.addAttribute("successRegister", "Successfully registered using email: " + user.getEmail());
    return "redirect:/login";
}
```

User Details Service Class:

```
    @Override
@Transactional
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userService.findByUsername(username);

    Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
    grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + Role.USER));

    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), grantedAuthorities);
}
```

[image: DB Table Headers]

I am not sure what the best way to go about doing this is, I would appreciate any help as I've been trying to tackle this for some time now.

Comment: This samples you provided - all only for regular user, right? Because you set 'ROLE_USER' right on loading user details, for every user. This will not work for multiple roles.

Comment: Yes, ROLE_USER is for everyone while ROLE_ADMIN is for the admins. What's the best way to go about having multiple roles? I want it so that everyone that is signed up is a ROLE_USER, but only Admins can get ROLE_ADMIN if it's put on the database manually.

Comment: But do you release that in your sample all roles are not loaded from database,right ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, what do you mean by that?

Comment: Look at 'loadUserByUsername' method, there is 'return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), grantedAuthorities);' where 'grantedAuthorities' is local variable, not filled from database.  So 'ROLE_ADMIN' is never appears in application, for any user. Got it ?

Comment: I understand, so to connect it to the database, should I use the userservice to find the role of that user, then return that role in the loadUserByUsername method?

Comment: Like this: grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole()));
Instead of: grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + Role.USER));

So that it is filled from the database roles

Comment: Yep, you got the idea.

Comment: But when I try to login to the restricted page /admin/** it keeps redirecting to  /login?error even if the user has role USER_ADMIN

Comment: try to replace '.hasRole("ADMIN")' with '.hasAnyRole("ADMIN")' and add '.anyRequest().authenticated()' at the end of chain.